# How to use this in a dart constructor with private variables

Tags: dart, flutter

When I try to create a constructor in dart like `Student(this._name)` it doesn't work with private variables.

I have already tried using setters but it doesn't work either.

```
    class Student{

    var _id;
    var _name;

    Student(this.id, this.name);

    void set id(int id) => _id = id;
    void set name(String name) => _name = name;

    }
```

Comment: Sure, it does. It does *not* only if you make them optional named parameters (`Student({this._id, this._name});` would not be allowed)

Comment: Ok, so in a case with optional named parameters I would have to set the variables in the constructor body?

Comment: See my answer. Some hints. User proper types for fields instead of `var`. `var` is fine for local variables that are initialized when declared. Don't use public getters/setters for private fields if they don't contain additional logic. You can replace fields by getters/setters or vice versa at any time without breaking users of your code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is not supported because <strike>it would expose private implementation to the outside.</strike>

If you'd rename `var _id;` to `var _userId;` you would break code that uses your class just by renaming a private field.
*See instead the comment below my answer.*

```
  class Student{

    var _id;
    var _name;

    Student({this._id, this._name}); // error

    void set id(int id) => _id = id;
    void set name(String name) => _name = name;
  }
```

The alternative

```
  class Student{

    var _id;
    var _name;

    Student({int id, String name}) : _id = id, _name = name;

    void set id(int id) => _id = id;
    void set name(String name) => _name = name;
  }
```

Comment: The reason privately named parameters are not allowed is that you can't *call* with them from a different library. If you declare `foo({int _x}) {...}` then no other library can provide that argument because `foo(_x: 42)` is a different name in a different library. For instance methods, no other library would be able to override the methods. So, in general, named parameters are not allowed to have private names. (It's not because changing the name would break anyone, because noone could possibly be using that name at all).

Comment: Are there any comments on whether this solution is idiomatic Dart or not? It seems that hiding members (e.g., dependencies) from consumers is a concern that is intentionally avoided by the language choices in Dart

Comment: Wish Dart would just assume that this.id should set a private _id variable.

I understand this would make code "less flexible" but I think the benefit of keeping it the way it is right now is very limited

Answer (score 9):

You can use this notation

```
class Student {
  String _id;
  String _name;

  Student({required String id, required String name})
      : _id = id,
        _name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of you maybe struggle if the class was inheritance, you just need add coma (,) after initialize your private.

Example

```dart
class Animal {
  String _name;
  int _age;
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  String _race;
  Dog(String name, int age, {String? race}) : _race = race ?? "Wild", super(name, age);
}
```

Hope this code can help you.

Answer (score -1):

This notation is not valid because the variable is not `private` and its elements are just as accessible again.

DartLang says: **AVOID wrapping fields in getters and setters just to be ["safe"](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html).**